# structuring mysql large table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I ran into some issues with my mysql dababase table. I have a script that inserts like 200 rows every 5 , 10 minutes, including date_inserted and i have a query that shows last records inserted based on some joins (like 4 joins). The tables is like this :

`table :`
`id, location, int_id, in, out, steps, date_added`

and i have a join like this

```
...
join (
   select a.location, a.int_id, a.in, a.out, a .date_added
   from table a
   join (
      select location, int_id, max(date_added) as `date_added`
      from table
      group by location, int_id 
        ) b on b.location = a.location
          and b.int_id = a.int_id
          and b.date_added = a.date_added
) c on c.location like concat('%', b.location_name, '%')
    and c.int_id = b.interface_id
...
```

and as this table will grow up too 10 milion, 100 milion records the query will run slow and slow .

What is the optimal way to reduce the size of this table ? I read partition but i dont know if it;'s the best solution for me ? Or ?

Maybe to create a new database or table every month ?

I dont want to end up having to join a table with 100 milion records and increasing .

Thank you very much bbut i cannot figure it out how to scale this .

## UPDATE 1

`id : int primary key auto_increment , location varchar, int_id int, in bigint, out bigint, steps varchar, date_added timestamp`

I have a log server that every 5 minutes save in database a location name an interface id and some bigint counters for in and out (that alwas increment but i can reset them ) with a currect date of insert.
I`m doing a report in realtime to see this counters at the latest date inserted (if i reset them they will start from 0 and cannot use max(in) or max(out) in case of a group to speed select)

The question is : This table in like a half year will grow so much that this realtime report will be affected by the numbers of row in the table. What is the best way to split them to maintain a table with limited rows for the speed of the report. I dont want to delete old counters as i will create a detailed report for days / weeks/ months, but i dont want to have 100 milion records in only one table. I was thinking to create a monthly database and insert records for a month in database 2016_04_report , 2016_05_report ... etc

Comment: if it's just the last insert timestamp why not store a cache table and store the timestamp there?

Comment: cache table ? how ? because i need the respective counters (in and out) and i may reset them and if i do so i need them 0 at the last insert for that location and that inferface_id

Comment: I think then, it would be easier if you explain what you are trying to achieve, what data you are storing and why?  Then let us try help you, because at the minute it's ambiguous.  Also a simpler solution may exist if we knew what we were solving.

Comment: ok i will edit post and show u the type of columns

Comment: I'm not sure a DBMS is the right solution for what you are trying to achieve actually, but off the top of my head you could consider using `CASE WHEN COUNT(date_added) > 1 THEN MAX(in) ELSE 0 END AS max_in` to work around the aggregation.

Comment: So how come you need to perform so many joins in order to get historical data back about a few hundred inserts that you've done within last few minutes? You went about this in such a wrong way, from doing joins and subqueries that make everything harder to read (a subquery is equal to join, you could have just joined everything). Also there's a `like` search with two wildcards - that's going to be fun to run with 100m records and increasing. You need to cache your data like @ash suggested, not run live queries on the whole data set.

Comment: because i have locations in one table, interface_id per location in another table and i need to join them . I use the like because i have a location 'Location' with interface_id ( 1 , 2 , 3) and the script that insert in database for some location insert (Location 1, 1 ) , (Location 2, 2) because of a programmer error and i need to match Location with Location 1 , Location 2, Location 3 because they are same location

Comment: @ash there will always be `count(date_added) > 1` but i may now reset the counter to 0 and for the next insert the counter will be 0 and still have > 50 count(date_added) so i want to print 0 not max(in)

Comment: When dealing with volumes of data you should avoid `LIKE` and use as many integers, chars and enumeration column types with appropriate  composite keys and indexes.  `varchar` is slow, InnoDB is slower than MyISAM for searching; MyISAM would lock-up the whole table for every insert = a problem for frequent insert/updates (dead-lockable)

Comment: @ash i know but right now it's impossible as i get the insert from someone else who made this error and dont want to corect it. so i can't do anything right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid `on c.location like concat('%', b.location_name, '%')` for there to be any hope for performance.

Does your query search the entire table?  If so, you will eventually be IO-bound and have no hope of performance.

Can you summarize the new data each day (or other time interval), thereby avoiding looking at the big table?

```
INDEX(location, int_id, date_added)
```

in that order will help some.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; what you provided left out too many details.  Also provide the entire query.  With those, I might have a comment on `PARTITIONing`.  (It is unlikely that partitioning will help any.)